# SQL Reporting Services: Problemas com Setas no Gráfico

Tags: reporting-services

Estou com um problema, não consigo remover essas setas no Reporting Services no Visual Studio 2013.
[image: Setas do gráficos]

Answer (score 4):

Você deve selecionar o gráficos e pressionar F4 para acessar suas propriedades.

Siga para a área SmartLabels e altere a propriedade CalloutLineAnchor para alterar a seta e/ou colocar outro simbolo

Você pode selecionar a propriedade Disabled para remover todos os símbolos também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]